# Missing Symbols on AppCenter for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, symbols, visual-studio-app-center, hockeyapp

I've got a React native app and after migrating from HockeyApp to AppCenter I can't get Diagnostics on my iOS app on AppCenter because the symbols UUID required doesn't match with the one I uploaded and I don't know why.

I did this to get the `.dsym` file
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/ios-symbolication#finding-the-dsym-bundle

Can someone help me to understand this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it, thanks to the AppCenter support.

The problem was that I wasn't uploading the good dSYM file.

The good one for me was in the **DerivedData** -> `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_APP/Build/Products/Debug-xxx/xxx.dSYM`

It's working now